# Android - Reading in specific values from a text message

Tags: android, sms

I am developing an Android app which needs to read text messages - I have the code to read in the whole text message, however is it possible to assign part of the message to different variables?

For example, the text message will contain a GPS Latitude and Longitude, how can I assign the aforementioned values separately, to separate variables?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must parse this String. [Here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html) is some example.

Comment: Brilliant, I was thinking of using space as a delimiter, but I thought I would have to loop through the whole message to split the strings. This makes it look very easy, thanks!