# Convert String to Double excluding part of the string

Tags: android, string, double

How to convert double to a string value that I get from the spinner, for example: "10 (ton)."

In summary:
How to convert string to double and delete the part (ton)?

I need only the value 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is using Java's substring method in the String class.

The signature is:

```
substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Where **endIndex** equals to the index of the last character you want to include + 1.

In the case of your example, it will look like this:

```
String myString = "10 (ton)";
Double dbl = Double.parseDouble(myString.substring(0, 2));
```

Here is the link to the method: 
[Java substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

You must parse this String. [Here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html) is some example. Also use [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120391/android-reading-in-specific-values-from-a-text-message/9120594#9120594).

Comment: I could not make it work, could test whether the code that gave me correct?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to get rid of "(ton)" which can be achieved by using a String method for example

```
String inputString = "10 (ton)";
String str = inputString.split(" ")[0];
```

After that just parse the double Value

```
Double dbl = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

BTW: Not sure whether you want to go from double to string or vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

Check these methods `Double.parseDouble()` and `Double.toString()` use these functions for converting double to string or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar problem.
for correct formatting EditText text content to double value i use this code:

```
try {
        String eAm = etAmount.getText().toString();
        DecimalFormat dF = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        Number num = dF.parse(eAm);
        mPayContext.amount = num.doubleValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mPayContext.amount = 0.0d;
    }
```

this is independet from current phone locale and return correct double value.

hope it's help;